# Lower and remove special character of file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a script, which lower and remove special character multiple text files.

my files in folder like this:

```
- ⚡ Document.txt
- [Review] Test File.txt
```

i want remove special char of filename like this

```
- document.txt
- review test file.txt
```

i've tried like this, but only lower filename. how to remove special character?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd %currentfolder%

for %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"

   for %%A in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u w x y z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
   ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
endlocal
```

Before

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
set "validchars=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890. "

pushd "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%b IN (*) DO (
 set "newname="
 set "oldname=%%b"
 call :validate
 if /i "%%b" neq "!newname!" ren "%%~sb" "!newname!"
)

popd

GOTO :EOF

:validate
if not defined oldname goto :eof
set "c1=%oldname:~0,1%"
set "oldname=%oldname:~1%"
if "!validchars:%c1%=!" neq "%validchars%" set "newname=%newname%%c1%"
goto validate
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

I predict it will have problems with some unicode characters and the usual suspects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pure `powershell` for this, or if you feel like continuing the use `batch-file`, just call `powershell` to assist:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell "$string='%%~ni';$String.tolower() -replace '[\W]', ''"') do echo ren "%%~i" "%%a%%~xi"
```

Note the `echo` at the end of the line, that is to test functionality by printing to screen before you do the actual renaming. Only remove `echo` when you're happy with the printed results.